# Changing encryption algorithm

Tags: java, md5, aes

Does anyone know good tutorials to change `PBEWithMD5AndDES` encryption algorithm to `AES` for a Java application? Specially , I want to know what precautions I should take while changing this algorithm to more secure one. Any important test cases to check before and after algorithm changes. Another question is since I have used `PBEWithMD5AndDES` , most of the user passwords are encrypted using that algorithm. So if I change my algorithm to `AES` , how do I make sure that decryption of passwords happen with old algorithm while I can still use new algorithm for any new encryption.

Comment: SHA-256 is not an encryption algorithm, it's a hashing algorithm!

Comment: aw! MD5 to SHA-256. I feel weird in my gut. Is it possible?

Comment: @Nishant: Why wouldn't it be possible? I don't see any problem with that.

Answer (score 4):

Normally you wouldn't encrypt a users password, you'd just hash it with a salt instead.

Migrating from one encryption system to another is going to be a bit of a pain, as I see it you have two options:

1. During the upgrade process decrypt then re-encrypt all the passwords
2. Add a flag indicating the encryption method used. All existing passwords will obviously be set to the current standard. New users will be set to whatever method you choose and you can migrate other users when they change their password.

Comment: you can migrate other users when they're logging in with their password encrypted with the old technique, since they'll be entering the plain text version of it. No need to wait until they change their password if it matches the old method.

Comment: @chelmertz: good point. Either way you need to keep track of which encryption method you used.

Answer (score 3):

If you've already got data encrypted in format `a`, and you want to start using another encryption scheme, `b`, I can think of two ways to accomplish this:

1. **Decrypt all of your data and re-encrypt it using `b`.**  This approach would be good when you can take your data store offline and "fix everything at once."
2. **For each item you attempt to decrypt, try to decrypt it using `b` first.  If that fails, decrypt it using `a`.  The next time you try to encrypt something, make sure you use `b`.**  This approach could be used when you can't take your data store offline, but you want to encrypt all of your data using another algorithm.  All of your data will eventually be encrypted using the other algorithm.

Comment: What would you suggest when the data to decrypt is huge?

Comment: Do you mean when your *data store* contains a large number of records or when an individual record is large?

Comment: @David - Yes , large number of records and the problem is i implement scheme 'b' , I have to remove scheme 'a', so how do I achieve what you mentioned in 2 ?

Comment: @David: "All of your data will eventually be encrypted using the other algorithm" is only true if you can recognize newly encrypted data someway, which should be included with that solution :)

Comment: @chelmertz: true.  I was making an (unspoken) assumption that, they'd take an action (like logging in) and if that fails, then they'd assume that they decrypted using an incorrect algorithm.  However that introduces another set of problems.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no problem changing algorithms.  What you need to do is decrypt the cipher text and then encrypt the resulting plain text with the new algorithm.  That's straightforward.  If you are going to perform this transition over time, I would suggest creating a new database table that keeps track of whether a particular entity (based on unique id) has been transfered to the new algorithm.  If it has, then you simply use the new algorithm to decrypt it and you can forget about it, if not, then you use the old algorithm to decrypt it.  Regardless though, all new encryption should be performed with the new algorithm.

Now, there's a second issue here.  Why are you bothering to decrypt passwords? Just save the hash of the password and forget about it.  If you are able to decrypt passwords, you introduce a potential vulnerability.  If a malicious user can get a hold of your key you use to encrypt those passwords, then they could access the plain text of the password.  Not only could the user then use that information to compromise your system, if your users use the same username/password combination for other sites, those accounts would be compromised as well.  You should only store a hash of the password (SHA is a good one, don't use MD5) and then when the user attempts to log in, you hash the input and compare the two results.  You have no need to know what the plain text password is.

Answer (score 1):

you may look into ESAPI - java  http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/

ESAPI 1.4 was using PBEWithMD5AndDES, but in 2.0 they introduced AES

check their mail chain [here](https://lists.owasp.org/pipermail/esapi-dev/2010-January/000515.html)

you may check the difference between the two implementations

Answer (score 1):

`PBEWithMD5AndDES` is a method of taking a user's password and from it deriving an encryption scheme that can be used to protect further data. It is not a method of verifying a password, nor of encrypting one.

If you are only interested in password validation, then decrypt the passwords and replace them with a secure hash and in future match the hashes. You will also need your password reminder service to a password reset service.

The question is where is the password you are passing into the PBE algorithm coming from? If it is a fixed password for your application, then you just need to replace it and perform some kind of rolling upgrade. As an observation, if you are storing encrypted data as text, either hex or base-64 encoded, there are characters that cannot appear in the text output and which you can hence prepend to indicate a newer encryption scheme. For example the `:` character does not appear in base-64. That will allow you to identify what has been upgraded and what has not.

If the passwords are coming from the user, then each user has their own password derived cipher. In this case you can only re-encrypt whatever data has been encrypted with the user's cipher when the user provides their password.

The most direct replacement is going to be along the lines of `PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES`. Unfortunately, this is not supported by Java 6, so you will need a 3rd party JCE library such as [Bouncy Castle](http://bouncycastle.org). Bouncy Castle offers `PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC`, which would be a suitable replacement.

The process of upgrading the cipher is a challenge. Whatever data has been encrypted with DES can only be decrypted with the user's password. I assume you do not have access to the passwords. This means you can only re-encrypt the data when the person who knows the password provides it. You are going to have a long period of time when your system contains a mixture of ciphers, so you need a way of identifying what is converted.

If we are talking about files, you could change the file suffix, or the folder they are stored in. If we are talking about BLOBs in a database, you could add an extra column to the database table to say what the encryption method is. If neither of those are possible you could add some form of header to the data to indicate that it has been encrypted in a new way. That's slightly risky as your existing data has no header and there is an outside chance it will match the new header by accident.

It may also be advisable to keep a list of which users have not yet had their data converted so you can prompt them to convert.